# Why does sizeToFit remove my entire label?

Tags: ios, uilabel, sizetofit

I am trying to use the function sizeToFit. It works perfectly throughout the application however it does not work in the code below. Further to that, if it can't be done the way I am doing it please advise.

```
            self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 67.0, 290, 50)];
        self.label.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:74.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];

        self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 380.0, 300, 400)];
        self.description.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:15];
        self.description.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.description.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
        self.description.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.description.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.description.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.description sizeToFit];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.description];


        self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 228)];
        self.image.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //[scrollView addSubview:self.image];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.image];



        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I passed the data using this method from a different controller

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *item = [_articleListmain objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    // set the article image
    [cell.image setImageWithURL:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];
    [cell.label setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [cell.description setText:[item objectForKey:@"description"]];



        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the label is empty, `sizeToFit` shrinks it down to nothing. That's the point. Set some text then call `sizeToFit` and the label will be just big enough for the text.

Comment: The information is coming from an array which is called by self.description

Comment: That doesn't matter. You need to call `sizeToFit` after setting the `text` property of the label, not before. In the code you posted you are not setting the `text` property before calling `sizeToFit`.

Comment: Call `sizeToFit` on the label after setting the label's text.

Comment: I needed to look at it from the other .h files... respect

Comment: @RobertFarr Huh? What does this have to do with .h files?

Comment: Apologies, not my .h files but my other controller where the data was being set. I adjusted the question to show my code that was in a collection view. I took your advice and added the code there

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I have a customized cell and a separated tableview controller. it turns out that we should set the NumberOfLines and SizeToFit in the controller, not the cell.